# iOS UITextView : URL Detection for links with country domain and without "http" prefix

Tags: ios, swift, url

As of iOS 9.2, UITextView URL Detection is working like below:

```
check this out google.com -> OK

check this out google.com.my -> NOT OK (its not highlighting)

check this out http://google.com -> OK

check this out http://google.com.my -> OK
```

My question is how to make the textview auto highlight the second example above (google.com.my) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't create custom url dedection schemes.

You can use NSregularExpression to parse custom domains (simply extract strings as url) Then you could use NSAttributedString to mark the links in different color.